# Tweepy Cannot get media url

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to show image url of tweet. I get tweet data by using get_tweet like this code.

```
tweet_ids = [166xxxxxxxxx]

tweets = client.get_tweets(tweet_ids, tweet_fields=['author_id'],media_fields=['preview_image_url'])
```

Then I try to get list of media from the includes object

```
media = {m["media_key"]: m for m in tweets.includes['media']}
```

It show error like this.

```
---> 13 media = {m["media_key"]: m for m in tweets.includes['media']}
     14 for media in tweets.media:
     15   attachments = tweet.attachments

KeyError: 'media'
```

If I use for loop to get url like this.

```
for media in tweets.media:
  attachments = tweet.attachments

  if(attachments['media_keys'] != None):

   media_keys = attachments['media_keys']
   print(media[media_keys[0]].preview_image_url)
```

It show error.

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'media'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Try including `expansions=['attachments.media_keys']` as a parameter when calling `get_tweets`?